# Webbrowser wants to download json instead of showing it

Tags: c#, json, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a `webBrowser` that show a page for authentification.

When the authentification is completed, the browser is supposed to show a JSON.

But with the c# .NET (4.0) `webBrowser`, when the JSON is ready to by displayed, it want to download the page instead of just showing it...

how can I change it ? I didn't find what I wanted on docs and forums

Answer (score 0):

You can use CefSharp.Wpf from nuget package and use ChromiumWebBrowser and load

the url

```
chormiumBrowser.Load("http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo");
```